# Chance of unique value in binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Say we have a binomial distribution $X \sim B(n, p)$, then we get
$$\mathbb{P}[X = k] = {n \choose k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1 - p)^{n - k}.$$
Denote this by $\mathbb{P}_k$, then assume we have $N$ unknown samples $(X_i)_{i = 1}^N$ from this distribution. Then the chance that one of these samples $X_i = k$ is unique among the $N$ samples depends on the value of $k$ and $N$, and is related to the question of how many of the $N$ samples do we expect to have a certain value. That is, if $X_i$ is an extreme outlier it has a high chance to be unique, or if $N$ is very small any outlier is likely to be unique.

I think that this gives us another binomial distribution, where $N$ is the number of trials and the probability $p = \mathbb{P}_k$. So would we get the following?
$$\mathbb{P}[X_i \text{ is unique}] = N \cdot \mathbb{P}_k \cdot (1 - \mathbb{P}_k)^{N - 1}$$

My main question is however: How many of the $N$ samples do I expect I need to draw before I'm likely to find a unique value among the $N$ samples? That is, say that I want to be 50% sure that the sample I took from the $N$ samples is unique ($\alpha = 0.5$), how many samples am I expected to take before I find a sample where the probability that it is unique is larger than $\alpha$?

Clearly an upper bound is $N_0 = N$ samples, which implies we know all $N$ samples and can pick the unique ones (we can assume $n$ and $N$ are very large and $p \geq 0.95$, so unique values are very likely to exist in the fist place). But there must be better approaches, as outliers are likely to exist and we are likely to find such outliers before having gone through all samples.

Comment: Your statement is not clear.  What does $\mathbb P[X_i\,\text {is unique}]$ mean?  It would not appear to depend on $k$, for example.  And why would you multiply by $N$?  Did you mean to say something like "the probability that exactly one of the $N$ samples has exactly $k$ success"?  Of course, that does not depend on $i$.

Comment: Hmm, let me give a concrete example. Say you draw 10.000 times from a distribution $B(n, p)$ and put those in a box. Then I come and one by one draw from the box. My goal is to draw a unique value. If I draw a certain value, I can calculate the odds that this value is unique among the 10.000 samples. Now I am trying to figure out how many times I expect to draw from the box before I decide that a certain value has such a high probability of being unique, that I go for it. This probability depends on the value I draw from the box ($X_i = k$) and on the number of samples in the box ($N$).

Comment: Why not just write out a clear, precise, definition and problem statement?  Once again, what you write for $\mathbb P[X_i\,\text{is unique}]$ really doesn't make sense.

Comment: It would also help to say something about the relative sizes.  Are we, say, to guess that $n$ is very large compared to the sample size?  That makes a big difference, as you could then assume that the probability that you draw a unique value is (essentially) independent of the draws you have previously made (other, of course, than that we can't have already seen that particular draw).

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of the problem statement are unclear. I see that what I write for " $X_i$ is unique" might not make sense, but I do not know how to write it down correctly. Regardless, what is unclear about the main question? With regards to the relative sizes: clearly those make a big difference and would make the question easier, but I'm trying to solve this in terms of $n, p, k, N$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: As I sad, the definition of $\mathbb P[X_i\,\text {is unique}]$ makes no sense.  Aside from the points I have already made, surely the definition must be *conditional*, right?  That is, it depends on the observations you have made prior to the $i^{th}$ draw.  For instance, the uniqueness of the $9999^{th}$ draw has almost nothing to do with the uncertain outcome of the final draw, and depends almost entirely on the prior known draws.

Comment: That conditioning is going to make it extremely hard to come up with a closed formula.  Again, in some limiting cases ($n>>N$ seems likely to me) you might be able to get away with ignoring the conditioning, because you are likely to hit a "rare" outcome pretty soon.

Comment: I don't think it is conditional, right? The knowledge of the prior samples does not impact the odds of a certain value being unique among $N$ other samples (other than that indeed the $i$-th sample only needs to be unique among the remaining $N-i$ samples). Perhaps a better formulation is then: given that you have taken $N$ samples from a binomial distribution, and I draw one value from these $N$, can I express the probability that this value is unique among the $N$ samples?

Comment: There is no probability attached to the known samples, they are known.  You can try to short circuit the problem by splitting each possible sample into "common" or "rare" but this fails too as the definition of "rare" changes as you draw more samples.

Comment: I suggest:  try to work out the case where $n>>N$.  To do it, split the outcomes into "common" and "rare" according to whatever threshold you like for "rare".  Then assume that you are likely to find a rare one before you have sampled too much (so the answer would then be $\frac 1{p_{rare}}$).  Then build a simulator and test this.  I wouldn't expect it to work  well in all cases.

Comment: The value will be maximized for the smallest $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N+1}<\mathbb P_k.$